# Convert to JOIN

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a correlated sub query, which is taking 16 Minutes to execute how can i convert it to join or optimize it.

```
SELECT SSF.SM_StockCode, SSF.ST_ItemSize FROM  Stock AS SSF 
WHERE SSF.SM_StockCode = (
    SELECT SM_StockCode
    FROM  Stock AS SSFAI
    WHERE SSFAI.ST_StockCode = SSF.ST_StockCode
    ORDER BY SSFAI.ST_ItemSize ASC
    LIMIT 1
) GROUP BY SSF.SM_StockCode
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the converted query since you use `LIMIT 1` on your sub-query:

```
SELECT SSF.SM_StockCode, SSF.ST_ItemSize 
  FROM Stock AS SSF INNER JOIN Stock AS SSFAI
    ON SSF.ST_StockCode = SSFAI.ST_StockCode
GROUP BY SSF.SM_StockCode
ORDER BY SSF.ST_ItemSize ASC
```

But from what I understand, the query is like this with `IN` operator:

```
SELECT SSF.SM_StockCode, SSF.ST_ItemSize FROM  Stock AS SSF 
WHERE SSF.SM_StockCode IN (
    SELECT SM_StockCode
    FROM  Stock AS SSFAI
    WHERE SSFAI.ST_StockCode = SSF.ST_StockCode
    ORDER BY SSFAI.ST_ItemSize ASC
    LIMIT 1
) GROUP BY SSF.SM_StockCode
```

On the other hand, I noticed that you are only selecting and comparing the same ID in the same table which doesn't make much sense. It's simply like this:

```
  SELECT SSF.SM_StockCode, SSF.ST_ItemSize 
    FROM Stock AS SSF
GROUP BY SSF.SM_StockCode
ORDER BY SSF.ST_ItemSize ASC
```

Comment: Result return by original and this query are different.

Comment: Only YOU can determine which is correct.

Comment: I only have to optimize the original query,I don't want to modify result.

Comment: Please check my updates.

Comment: We can't use IN with Limit in Sub Query. No of records return by Original query are 1582 and by this query are 3892.

Answer (score 0):

> IN sql-server ,use a join operation(self) ?

```
select a.SM_stockCode,a.ST_ItemSize from stock a join SM_StockCode b on a.SM_stockcode=b.SM_stockcode order by a.SM_stockcode
```